# How to start exactly two child processes in C?

Tags: c

I'd like to start two child processes in a C programm. I use `fork()` twice, but when checking the `pid`s it looks as if four processes started:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <wait.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    pid_t one = fork();
    pid_t two = fork();

    if (one == 0) {
        printf("child pid = %d\n", getpid());
    }   

    if (two == 0) {
        printf("child pid = %d\n", getpid());
    }   

    if (one != 0 && two != 0) {
        wait(NULL);
        printf("parent pid = %d\n", getpid());
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
g@x:dir$ ./twochilds
child pid = 11408
child pid = 11407
child pid = 11409
child pid = 11409
parent pid = 11406
```

Answer (score 5):

`fork()` duplicates the process, its return value in parent process is the actual child pid, and 0 in son address space. 
Let's follow what's going on assuming all calls to `fork()` succeeded.

```
pid_t one = fork();

                          (created by parent)  (created by child_1)
     Parent ---  Child_1 ---  Child_2 ---         Child_3
|   one > 0   |  one = 0  |  

pid_t two = fork(); 

|   one > 0   |  one = 0  |   one > 0 |   one = 0
|   two > 0   |  two > 0  |   two = 0 |   two = 0

if (one == 0) { (Will be executed by child_1 and child_3)
    printf("child pid = %d\n", getpid());
}   

if (two == 0) { (Will be executed by child_2 and child_3
    printf("child pid = %d\n", getpid());
}   

if (one != 0 && two != 0) { (Will be executed by parent only)
    wait(NULL);
    printf("parent pid = %d\n", getpid());
}
```

That is why you have 5 lines printed.

---

If you want exactly 2 child processes, you can do the following:

```
pid_t pid = fork();
if (pid == -1) {
    // handle error
} else if (pid == 0) { 
    // son process 1
} else {
    pid = fork();
    if (pid == -1) { 
        // handle error
    } else if (pid == 0) { 
        // son process 2
    } else {
        // initial parent process
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to ensure that the second `fork()` is not executed in the first child. For example:

```
  pid_t one, two;

  if ((one = fork()) == 0) {
    printf("child pid = %d\n", getpid());
  }
  else if ((two = fork()) == 0) {
    printf("child pid = %d\n", getpid());
  }   
  else {
    if (one == -1 || two == -1) {
      puts("an error occurred");
    }
    wait(NULL);
    printf("parent pid = %d\n", getpid());
  }
```